# sorting dates in the form mm/dd/yy

Tags: python, sorting, date, tuples

I'm extremely new to Python and I was wondering how I would be able to sort a list of tuples where the second element of each tuple is another tuple, like this:

```
[ ('Adam', (12,16,1949) ), ('Charlie', (9,4,1988) ), ('Daniel', (11,29,1990) ),
('Ellie', (11, 28, 1924) ), ('Feenie', (2,10,1954) ), ('Harry', (8,15,1924) ),
('Iggy', (12, 29, 1924) ), ('Jack', (2,21,1920) )]
```

I want to sort the list by using the sorted function to organize from youngest to oldest, but when I tried my function:

```
def sort_ages(a:list):

    return sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1][2], reverse=True)

[('Daniel', (11, 29, 1990)), ('Charlie', (9, 4, 1988)), ('Feenie', (2, 10, 1954)),  ('Adam', (12, 16, 1949)), ('Ellie', (11, 28, 1924)), ('Harry', (8, 15, 1924)), ('Iggy', (12, 29, 1924)), ('Jack', (2, 21, 1920))]
```

It organizes it by ascending year, but doesn't seem to care about the month or day.
Most of the questions I found here had their dates in the form YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: is this from database ?

Comment: have you tried this code 
`import datetime
d = [ ('Adam', (12,16,1949) ), ('Charlie', (9,4,1988) ), ('Daniel', (11,29,1990) ),
('Ellie', (11, 28, 1924) ), ('Feenie', (2,10,1954) ), ('Harry', (8,15,1924) ),
('Iggy', (12, 29, 1924) ), ('Jack', (2,21,1920) )]
sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%y'),reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(xs, reverse=True, key=lambda (name, (m,d,y)): (y,m,d))
```

Converting to `datetime.date` isn't necessary, but it is perhaps a better expression of the meaning.

```
sorted(xs, reverse=True, key=lambda (name, (m,d,y)): datetime.date(y,m,d))
```

Comment: OP is using Python 3.x ([function annotation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) is only available in Python 3.x). [Tuple unpacking is removed in Python 3.x](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 0):

Make the key function to return a tuple that contains year, month, day in order.

```
def by_day(t):
    m, d, y = t[1]
    return y, m, d

def sort_ages(a:list):
    return sorted(a, key=by_day, reverse=True)
```

example output for the given list:

```
[('Daniel', (11, 29, 1990)),
 ('Charlie', (9, 4, 1988)),
 ('Feenie', (2, 10, 1954)),
 ('Adam', (12, 16, 1949)),
 ('Iggy', (12, 29, 1924)),
 ('Ellie', (11, 28, 1924)),
 ('Harry', (8, 15, 1924)),
 ('Jack', (2, 21, 1920))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_ages(a:list):

    return sorted(a, key=lambda x:(x[1][2], x[1][0], x[1][1]), reverse=True)
```

Sorts according to year, then month, then date